# Loading images via SDWebImage eats project's memory

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, crash, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have some issue when I make loading of images in `collectionView`(the `colectionCell` contains also `horizontalCollection`).

```
showActivityIndicator()
imageView.sd_setOptimizedImageWithURL (url, placeholderImage:  placeholder) {
    self?.hideActivityIndicator()
})
```

I also do this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        hideActivityIndicator()
        seshImageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
}
```

Then I am scrolling up/down and eventually a crash happens.
Using Allocation from Instruments I see that memory is growing rapidly, but I can't fix it yet.
Please review my screen. `TotaBytes` has achieved almost 6GB and then crash.
[image] 
Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

//my custom cell which represent a UICollectionViewCell you can define it using nib or using code

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
class TDtopicCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        loaderAct!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
        loaderAct!.startAnimating();
        addShadow();
    }
    func downLoadImage(_url:String) -> Void {

        image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: _url),placeholderImage:nil, options:SDWebImageOptions.RetryFailed , completed: {[weak self]
            (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            // do your custom logic here
            if let wSelf = self {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    wSelf.clear()
                }

            }
            })
    }
    func clear() -> Void {
        if((loaderAct) != nil)
        {
            loaderAct!.removeFromSuperview();
        }
    }
}
```

//this method belong to my custom UICollectionView 
//this would surely solve your memory usage problem as  feteching images using lazy loading

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as!TDtopicCell
    eachTDtopic=collectionData![indexPath.item];
    //eachTDtopic?.topicImage is image path ------------------------------------------
    cell.downLoadImage((eachTDtopic?.topicImage)!);
    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, will try it a bit later, seems the problem is not only with image loading. When I comment all code and scroll just empty cells the memory continue growing. Maybe you faced with it? Is it usual? Thanks!

Comment: yes, I am using  reuseIdentifiers, but seems I find the mistake thanks for your help, and lazy loading was also helpful thing!